# Parallel Listening of messages in rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have a requirement, where we create queues in rabbitMq on application startup with direct exchange, and then have to assign a single listener to each queue. We implemented that using Spring AMQP with the following configuration

```
 @Bean(name= {"dispatcherListener"})
 public SimpleMessageListenerContainer dispatcherListener() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    listenerContainer.setQueues(participantQueues());
    listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    listenerContainer.setMessageListener(subscriptionListener);
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    listenerContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
    return listenerContainer;
}
```

But then we faced a problem, with the above configuration. When we publish the message to multiple queues , then the listener is reading the messages serially from each queue. But we expected it to listen to messages from each queue independent of other queue parallely.

Can someone please guide me, where i went wrong ?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That's correct behavior, since the default `concurrency` is `1`, therefore we have only one listener for all queue.

Just consider to increase that value for your configuration.

More info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#listener-concurrency).

Comment: However, if you wish to always receive messages from the same queue on the same thread, you need a separate container for each.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would not be inclined to using multiple consumers, as the order of message could be lost and its of high priority for me. Creating a separate container would be better, but can i create listener containers in runtime ? , because new queues would be created dynamically and I need a separate container for each then

Comment: Yes , you can but be aware that you should supply it with all required application context infrastructure . Or just use BeanFactory.initializeBeean()!